# Adding GridView row headers? Or should I approach this differently?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to populate a table with data from an Oracle database, using ASP.NET 3.5 (VB.NET) in the following format:

[image: Mock up of data I want to display]

As you can see, there are header rows describing the data to the right.  Is there any way to accomplish this using a GridView?  I have tried looking into the GridView.Row class, but I can't find anything to add row headers.  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easiest for you to move the headers (that are currently in the first column), so that they are horizontally displayed in the first row (instead of the word "header").  The data should repeat vertically so it will have to be flipped around.

Alternatively, as long as you have a fixed number of columns you should look at binding the values to literals instead.  If you do not have a fixed number of records, then a grid which repeats horizontally is not a good idea for a web page.

The GridView control is suited for tabular, vertically-repeating data that is designed to be paged.